# linux mv - gone wrong: created 'something' (no directory) in root directory

Tags: linux, directory, mv

I'm a newbie to linux and console-working. Maybe someone can give me a short hint how to solve my problem best?

**what I meant to do**

I wanted to move a file from a directory a) to directory b) in my home-directory.

**What happened:**

By accident the destination-path was incomplete:

My command script was:

```
mv filename.extension /destDirectory
```

- filename.extension => the name of the file I wanted to move
- destDirectory => the name of my destination folder

Without further reflecting it, I confirmed the give error-statement 'Permission denied' by adding 'sudo' to my statement.
When I list my root-directory, I can *see *the name of my by accident created 'directory'. If I try to open the directory (cd destDirectory) I get the message it's "not a directory".

**what I would like to achive now**

1. I want to tidy up my root directory (without any further massing around!)
2. I'd like to move the file away from root directory, directly into my home-destination-folder!
3. for future learning my lessons: what is is if console gives me the hint "it's not a directory?"

Thanks for help :-)!

Comment: Reverse it, this IS the file: `mv  /destDirectory <maybe a path>/filename.extension`

Comment: Don't just use `sudo` blindly if you're not doing sysadmin stuff. And even then be careful.

Comment: Thanks for help (stoney) and advice (Robert), It worked perfectly, problem is solved! :-)